# ASP.NET MVC - one validator on two textfields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got an interesting client requirement.

I have a control that needs to be displayed like so:

```
Date of xxx     [ mm ][ yy ]
```

There is a label with two textfields - one for month in digits and one for year in digits.

Although there are two text fields, we want the validation to run once validating both fields.

Also there are a number of these controls on a page.  How would be the best way to package this up so that I can call:

```
@Laberfor(x => x.Datexxx)
@EditorFor(x => x.Datexxx)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your control is strongly typed, you could implement `IValidatableObject` and its `Validate` method.

Assuming your model looks like this:

```
public class CombinedDateViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public int month { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int year { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {        
        if(month > 12 || month < 1)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Month is out of range");
        if(year < 0 || year > 2020)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Year is out of range");
    }
}
```

The yielded validation results will manifest in the validation summary.